# Is it safe to cut these wires?

Tags: basic

My kid got a face mask with flashing eyes, but there's also some annoying sounds that comes with it. Is it totally safe to cut the white wires or could the awesome flashing lights stop working too (red and black wires)?

Do we need to see the other side of the board?

Gray wire is power. Yellow some additional connector.

[image]

Comment: No need to cut. Desolder just one of the white wires on the PCB and the speaker should shut up.

Comment: should be safe to cut (you only need one) of the white speaker wires... tape it with Sellotape or electrical tape, just to be sure

Comment: @JYelton in theory, sure, but the asker probably doesn't have soldering tools.  And even someone who did would probably just cut the wire leaving enough that they could strip it and solder it back if they ever wanted to.  Nail clippers, scissors... even just flexing it back and forth a bunch of times until it breaks (though the last has some likely acceptable chance of lifting a pad)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cut one white wire to interrupt the speaker. Cut it in the middle and you will be able to strip and reconnect if you ever want to. It is most unlikely that the LEDs and speaker are interdependent.

Comment: Indeed, there's about a 99% chance that this will work, and it's not an uncommon toy modification.  But it's politically useful to do it before the fact that there *once were* sound effects is discovered.